# React Material UI Button component with hookrouter

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hookrouter

I am trying to migrate a class component React app to functional components with hooks.

When using class components I use to pass a [Link](https://material-ui.com/es/api/link/) component to a [Button](https://material-ui.com/api/button/) component since I was using [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) library.

But now I am trying to use [Paratron/hookrouter](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter) library for routing but I get an error when passing an `A` component to the Button:

> **TypeError:** props.href is undefined

My code now looks like this:

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Grid, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { A } from 'hookrouter';
import './styles.css';

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Grid container spacing={24} className="landing">
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Button 
            variant="contained" 
            color="primary" 
            size="large"
            component={A}
            to="/login"
          >Login</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Button 
            variant="contained" 
            color="secondary" 
            size="large"
            component={A}
            to="/contact"
          >Contact us</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I guess this `A` component does not contain an `href` property. Not sure how to proceed. Any comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide '*href*' prop, not '*to*' prop.

```
<Fragment>
  <Grid container spacing={24} className="landing">
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Button 
        variant="contained" 
        color="primary" 
        size="large"
        component={A}
        href="/login" //href
      >Login</Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Button 
        variant="contained" 
        color="secondary" 
        size="large"
        component={A}
        href="/contact" //href
      >Contact us</Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Fragment>
```

I also had to wrap A with class component, since A is probably function component, and they can't hold a ref (which is required by button component prop)

You can refer to this working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-txz8c?fontsize=14) demo

Comment: I completely forgot. That `to` property was related to the `Link` component. So, this `href` is related to the `A` component. Thank you.